What is the correct particular solution(and solved coefficients) for this non-homogenous recurrence relation?
I need some help with the following non-homogenous recurrence relation,
$$a_{n+3} - 3a_{n+2} + 3a_{n+1} - a_n = 3 + 5n$$
The characteristic equation is third order with repeated root $1$. I know that our homogeneous solution is $a_n^{(h)} = A + Bn + Cn^2$.
We were told that this should be our particular solution $a_n^{(p)} = Dn^3+En^4$.
Could you explain me how did we get it?
Thank you.

In the LHS of $$a_{n+3} - 3a_{n+2} + 3a_{n+1} - a_n = 3 + 5n \tag{1}$$
we recognize the "third order discrete derivative" $\Delta_3(a_n)$ of sequence $a_n$ (see explanations below). The fact that a third order derivative is equal to $3+5n$ means that $a_n$ can be "discretely" integrated 3 times as :
$$a_n=\underbrace{(1/2)n^3+(5/24)n^4}_{\text{particular sol. of (1)}}+\underbrace{C_0+C_1n+C_2n^2}_{\text{gen. sol. of homogeneous equation ass. with (1)}}\tag{2}$$
where $C_0, C_1, C_2$ are arbitrary constants.
Explanations : if we admit in a provisional manner that the second derivative is
$$\Delta_2(a_n)=a_{n+2} - 2a_{n+1} + a_n\tag{3}$$
By index shifting, we have :
$$\Delta_2(a_{n+1})=a_{n+3}-2a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}$$
The difference $\Delta_2(a_{n+1})-\Delta_2(a_{n})$ is exactly the LHS of (1).
But, why is (3) a valid second derivative ? For a similar reason : if we set
$$\Delta_1(a_n)=a_{n+1} - a_n\tag{4}$$
(which is a reasonable choice for a discrete first order derivative), index shifting and difference with (4) help us to retrieve :
$$\Delta_1(a_{n+1})-\Delta_1(a_n)=(a_{n+2} - a_{n+1})-(a_{n+1} - a_n)$$
where we recognize the RHS of (3)...

See for example this answer
